# optimize mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like to know, how we can optimize mysql complex query?

I would like to diff ways to do it. Any suggestions/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aditya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: what does that means? why my every question, gets -1 impression? plz let me know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

optimizing mysql queries
[check here](http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/)